# Pegar o caminho antes de salvar a imagem CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou usando o seguinte método para salvar uma imagem, está funcionando corretamente:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }   
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Porém eu gostaria de antes de salvar a imagem, passar a rota dela para uma variável, mas está dando erro que devo converte lá, sou novato em CI se pudem me ajudar.

***Tentei fazer:***

```
$teste = $this->upload->data();
echo $teste;
```

Se eu faco um `foreach` vai mostrar todos os caminhos o que eu precisaria é mostrar apenas aquele especifico.

Comment: A "rota" seria o URL para a imagem gravada?

Answer (score -1):

[`$this->upload->data()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload#CI_Upload::data) é um [ARRAY associativo](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php). Para atribuir o valor do "caminho" do arquivo a uma variável precisamos especificar qual dos elementos do ARRAY queremos usar, o que, no seu caso, deve ser 'file_path':

```
$teste = $this->upload->data();
$file_path = $teste['file_path'];
echo $file_path;
```

Se vc quer uma URL para o arquivo vai ter que criá-la, porque até onde li na documentação, [`$this->upload->data()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload#CI_Upload::data) não retorna isso.

Isso aqui deve funcionar:

```
$teste = $this->upload->data();
$file_url = base_url("diretorio_upload/{$teste['file_name']}");
echo $file_url;
```

Answer (score -1):

Você vai usar:

$teste = $this->upload->data('file_path'); // Retorna o caminho absoluto do upload, atribuído no $config['file_path'].

$teste = $this->upload->data('full_path'); //Retorna o caminho absoluto do arquivo com o nome do arquivo + extensão.